# Using Rollback transaction with datatable sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, datatable

My project works properly but my issue is when there's an error occured in the second SP spInsertCorpPlan there is no value inserted in CorporationPlan while there is a value inserted in First table CorporationContact.

How to Rollback this.?

Please help.

```
                   for (int row = 0; row < dtContact.Rows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdContact = new SqlCommand("_spInsertCorpContact", _DentalConOpen());
                        cmdContact.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmdContact.Parameters.Add("@CorpCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Corporation.CorpCode;
                        cmdContact.Parameters.Add("@ContactType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dtContact.Rows[row][0].ToString();
                        cmdContact.Parameters.Add("@AreaCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dtContact.Rows[row][1].ToString();
                        cmdContact.Parameters.Add("@ContactNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dtContact.Rows[row][2].ToString();
                        cmdContact.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Corporation.User;

                        cmdContact.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmdContact.Dispose();
                        cmdContact.Connection.Close();
                    }
                    for (int row = 0; row < dtPlan.Rows.Count; row++)
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdPlan = new SqlCommand("_spInsertCorpPlan", _DentalConOpen());
                        cmdPlan.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmdPlan.Parameters.Add("@CorpCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Corporation.CorpCode;
                        cmdPlan.Parameters.Add("@PlanID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dtPlan.Rows[row][0].ToString();
                        cmdPlan.Parameters.Add("@EffectiveDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtPlan.Rows[row][2]);
                        cmdPlan.Parameters.Add("@ExpiryDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dtPlan.Rows[row][3]);
                        cmdPlan.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Corporation.User;

                        cmdPlan.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        cmdPlan.Dispose();
                        cmdPlan.Connection.Close();
                    }
```

**My Stored Procedures:**

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_spInsertCorpContact]
    @CorpCode varchar(20),
    @ContactType varchar(1),
    @AreaCode varchar(10),
    @ContactNo varchar(20),
    @User varchar (50)

AS
BEGIN

    Insert into CorporationContact 
    (CorpCode,
    ContactType,
    AreaCode,
    ContactNo,
    CreateBy,
    CreateDate,
    UpdateBy,
    UpdateDate)

    values
    (@CorpCode,
    @ContactType,
    @AreaCode,
    @ContactNo,
    @User,
    GETDATE(),
    '',
    null
    )
END
```

---

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[_spInsertCorpPlan]
    @CorpCode varchar(20),
    @PlanID varchar(20),
    @EffectiveDate DATETIME,
    @ExpiryDate DATETIME,
    @User varchar (50)

AS
BEGIN

    Insert into CorporationPlan
    (CorporationPlanID,
    CorpCode,
    PlanCode,
    EffectiveDate,
    ExpiryDate,
    CreateBy,
    CreateDate,
    UpdateBy,
    UpdateDate)

    values
    (@CorpCode+@PlanID,
    @CorpCode,
    @PlanID,
    @EffectiveDate,
    @ExpiryDate,
    @User,
    GETDATE(),
    '',
    null
    )
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlTransaction to achieve this. See the sample on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). However, make sure you the right isolation level otherwise you might end up creating deadlocks.

Essentially, your code would look something like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    try
    { 
         // Initialize and execute the first command
         SqlCommand command = GetFirstCommand();
         command.Connection = connection;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();

         // Initialize and execute the first command
         command = GetSecondCommand();
         command.Connection = connection;
         command.ExecuteNonQuery();

         transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         transaction.Rollback();
         throw;
    }
}
```